# Mouse stuttering in CS:GO and Far Cry 4

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse, far-cry-4

I've just got a new System (i5 4690K, 16GB RAM, MSI GTX 970) and I'm expiriencing some weird mouse lag in certain games. To visualize, I've made a quick video:

I've tried several other games (FS:X, Arma 3, Space Engineers) and theres no issue there. Also no issue on the Desktop. I've turned off Windows mouse acceleration, tried V-Sync and no V-Sync with frames limited and unlimited in CS:GO, and tried turning off raw mouse input in CS:GO.

I also tried changing the polling rate of my mouse (G700) to 125, 250, 500 and 1000 which led to no change. This hasn't happened on my old system and It's also not happneing on my Mac with the same mouse. I have the latest Nvidia drivers (347.09). Frankly, I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Could it be your system isn't fast enough to handle the inputs? (Usually, this lag happens when there is not enough CPU power or RAM to process the mouse movement). Different drivers; devices have different needs (for example, graphics tablets require more memory and CPU power as it has a secondary program under it to limit the area of the screen the cursor can move around in etc.)

Comment: Also, have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: I did try to restart. Here's my CPU load while playing CS: http://i.imgur.com/MlcmrmK.png Maximum 82% on any core.

Comment: Hm.. Did you have anything else open (other than CS)? | Though to say, mouse lag whilst not having max'd out CPU usage is weird, as it's only caused by slow connection; cable communication with the mouse (unlikely) or not having a good enough processor to process your inputs.

Comment: Barely anything, just the usual, Teamspeak, Spotify and the like. But RAM usage was at 62% at max usuage. The G700 is a wireless mouse but since it only happens in certain games I don't think thats the probem. And well, I've tried it on a local server so that should rule out the bad connection.

Comment: I'm not quite sure.. Because then it narrows down to the wireless connectivity (which is wrong, as you said it works seamlessly outside those games) or the game itself. Though strangely, the games you listed as working and not working (CS:GO, Space Engineers and ARMA 3) all use DirectX as their one of their APIs, which ruels software issues out of the question. | **But good luck finding out the issue.**

Comment: Yeah, no idea what fixed it but the issue kind of resolved itself. No idea what did it in the end but this is resolved. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You may want to flag it for a moderator to close it for you, since it was resolved, but no solution was found.

Comment: Uhm, how would I go about that? Just use the "other" reason when flagging and explain that the Issue is resolved?

Comment: Just use 'other', since it involves a custom reason.

Answer (score 1):

**This method might work**

1. Go to Control Panel and search Cursor Options
2. Disable Cursor Trails.

**This might also work for Windows 8 only.**

1. Navigate to settings (go to the top corner, swipe down and click settings)
2. Click Change PC Settings
3. Click PC and Devices then click Mouse and Touchpad.
4. Click the box underneath Touchpad and change to "No Delay"

**This might work for Windows 7 and 8**

1. Go to search and type *Change mouse settings*.
2. Click *Hardware* then click your mouse.
3. Click *Properties* then *Change settings*.
4. Click *Driver*
5. Click *Update Driver*

WARNING: If the Update fails then click roll back then retry.